# Entity Relationship Diagram - Relationship Strength?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to figure out under what circumstances I should use weak (non-identifying) relationships (where the primary key of the related entity does not contain a primary key component of the parent entity), verses when I should use strong (identifying) relationships (primary key of the related entity contains a primary key component of the parent entity).

For example, when designing an Entity Relationship Diagram , if I have two entities, (e.g. book and purchaser), how do I know when to choose the solid Crows Foot or the dashed Crows Foot to connect the two entities?

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is "Independent Existence"

A book exists whether it is purchased or not.

A purchaser exists whether they purchase a book or not.

However, a sales receipt for the purchase of a book cannot exist without purchaser and book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply S. Lott. Ok, so therefore the relationship between book and purchaser is a strong one, right?

Comment: @01010011: To me, Books and Purchasers don't have any sensible relationship, except via a "Purchase" or a "Transaction" or some intermediate.  What is the name of this relationship between book an purchaser?  "Purchased by"?  "Owned by?"  "Previously Purchased by?"  And what's the cardinality?  How many books can a purchaser be related to?  How many purchasers can a book be related to?

Comment: Yes, you are right, a relationship is needed, as well as a bridge entity.

Comment: Great, I really understand now. Thanks S. Lott